# What is the probability that $THTH$ occurs before $HTHH$ in an infinite sequence of coin flips?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk, random

> What is the probability that $THTH$ occurs before $HTHH$ in an infinite sequence of coin flips?

The expected number of flips until you first see $THTH$ is $6$, while the expected number until you first see $HTHH$ is $10$. Intuitively, I would guess that the probability that $THTH$ occurs before $HTHH$ is $3/4$. Is there a formal argument to compute this probability?

*Probabilistic model:* We denote by $(X_{n})_{n \geq 1}$ the random variable of coin flips, taking values in $\{H,T\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. We let $t_{THTH}$ be the first time that $THTH$ occurs in the sequence. We have
$$
\mathbb{E}[t_{H}] = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[t_{H} | X_{1} = H] + 
\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[t_{H} | X_{1} = T] = \frac{1}{2}  + 
\frac{1}{2} (\mathbb{E}[t_{H}] + 1  ).
$$

$$
\mathbb{E}[t_{TH}] = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[t_{TH} | X_{1} = H] + 
\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[t_{TH} | X_{1} = T]
$$

Comment: The expected time to get $THTH$ is 20, not 6.

Comment: Thank you, I will check again. How could you compute $20$ so quick? Do you have an efficient way to do this? I did the following:

Comment: We have $E[H] = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}   ( 1 + E[H] )$, hence $E[H] = 2$. Then $E[TH] = \frac{1}{2}   (1 + E[H] )+ \frac{1}{2}   ( 1 + E[TH] )$, so $E[TH] = 4$. It follows that $E[HTH] =  \frac{1}{2} (1 + E[TH] )+ \frac{1}{2}  ( 1 + E[HTH] )$, i.e. $E[HTH] = 6$. Finally, $E[THTH] =  \frac{1}{2}   (1 + E[HTH] )+ \frac{1}{2}  ( 1 + E[THTH] )$ and we conclude $E[THTH] = 8$.

Comment: That reasoning is not correct.  It looks like you want to define a DTMC with states $\{0, T, TH, THT, THTH\}\leftrightarrow \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and defining $X_i$ as teh random time to get to state 5, given we start in state $i$, gives $E[X_5]=0$ and  $$E[X_i] = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^5 P_{ij}E[X_j] \quad \forall i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$$

Comment: To be honest, I was following the approach of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521130/expected-value-of-flips-until-ht-consecutively/838575#838575.

Comment: At the link you give, I have added a comment on the incorrect reasoning given there, which (accidentally) produces the correct answer for the special case of only 2 flips.  While there is indeed a simple formula for the expected time to see any particular combination, and for the question you ask, the more basic (longer) calculation uses a DTMC, where you want to compute the expected *remaining* time given your current state.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out to me that error in this answer. I would like to rigorously model a Markov chain and strictly prove these results. See my updated question. Can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Why so much focus on expectations in question and comments? You want to find a *probability*, right?

Comment: Yes, true. But now, as I know that my initial thoughts were wrong, I would like to correct them and understand how it really works.

Comment: @drhab : The more basic question is to compute the expected time to THTH, and the asker has misconceptions about that (an incorrect value of 6 is claimed).   It may be better to focus on the simpler question the asker needs to understand than the more complicated one the asker is asking. Nevertheless I agree that for the second question, we want probabilities rather than expectations.

Comment: @MJD Thank you for the link. This especially because it seems to confirm my answer.

Comment: @user893458 : FYI:  Here are general notes on expected travel times in Markov chains. http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/markov-chains-travel-times.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Discern $p,p_{T},p_{H},p_{TH},p_{HT},p_{THT},p_{HTH}\in\left[0,1\right]$
where $p$ denotes the probability that $THTH$ occurs before $HTHH$
and e.g. $p_{TH}$ denotes the probability that $THTH$ occurs before
$HTHH$ under the extra condition that we start with $TH$.

Then we have the following equalities:

- $2p=p_{T}+p_{H}$
- $2p_{T}=p_{T}+p_{TH}$
- $2p_{H}=p_{HT}+p_{H}$
- $2p_{TH}=p_{THT}+p_{H}$
- $2p_{HT}=p_{HTH}+p_{T}$
- $2p_{THT}=1+p_{T}$
- $2p_{HTH}=p_{THT}$

(I avoided fractions, but things might become more clear if you divide both sides by $2$)

I find the solutions:

- $p_{THT}=\frac67$
- $p_{HTH}=\frac37$
- $p_{TH}=p_T=\frac57$
- $p_{HT}=p_H=\frac47$

and finally:$$p=\frac9{14}$$

Check me on mistakes, though.

Comment: This is consistent with results from simulation.

Answer (score 1):

We have states $\{H,T,HT,TH,THT,HTH,THTH,HTHH\}$ which are the prefixes of your strings. We can write down a Markov transition matrix for these states:

$$A = \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

This is an [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) already in canonical form \begin{pmatrix}Q&R\\0&I\end{pmatrix} thus we can find its fundamental matrix $N$ with

$$N = (I - Q)^{-1}$$
$$N = \frac{1}{7} \begin{pmatrix}
24 & 20 & 12 & 10 &  8 & 6\\
16 & 32 &  8 & 16 & 10 & 4\\
10 & 20 & 12 & 10 &  8 & 6\\
16 & 18 &  8 & 16 & 10 & 4\\
 8 & 16 &  4 &  8 & 12 & 2\\
 4 &  8 &  2 &  4 &  6 & 8
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Finally we can get the probabilities of our absorbing states given an initial probability vector of non-absorbing states $\vec p$with ${\vec p}^TNR$. Assuming we threw one coin already our initial state is $[1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0]^T$, and thus our final answer is that we end up with $THTH$ $9/14$th of the time and $HTHH$ $5/14$th of the time.